# How to eliminate /wiki/ directory in rewrite rule on a site dedicated for a wiki

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki, wiki

I have set up a subdomain of my site (for the purposes of this question I'll call it `wiki.example.com`), installed a wiki there, and set up URL rewrite according to the article on MediaWiki's website (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache).

But because my subdomain is purely dedicated to the wiki I was hoping that I could have my URLs in the format `wiki.example.com/ArticleName` rather than `wiki.example.com/wiki/ArticleName`.

I tried this by modifiying the rewrite rule in a way I thought would be correct:

```
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
```

Disclaimer: it may not have been exactly like that as the syntax I had written is no longer available for me to retype into this question.

This partially worked, as I could reach the page at `wiki.example.com/Main_Page` but none of the images or CSS had loaded.

I suspect the URL rewrite rule was trying to point everything at `index.php` but I'm wondering if there's any way to get a URL in the format `wiki.mysite.com/ArticleName`?

Comment: Just .htaccess is not enough, afaik. Did you check `LocalSettings.php` file?

Comment: I did make the necesary changes to LocalSettings.php.    

To be clear - I did get the 'normal' rewrite working, but I'm trying to acheive an alternative whereby the article name can be placed directly after the hostname.  I did make appropriate changes for this in localsettings.php

Answer (score 1):

The way which I hide that type of issue is by using *.htaccess*, and it actually works mighty well.

The code comes from my webhost, and you have to make some slight edits to fix it up to work, but it *should* work for you also.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

Basically, it is going to take the `/wiki/` folder out of the URL and it should fix your issue.